Error in Personalize / Experience component computed index field
I am testing an upgraded site (9.0.2 to 10.3.1). I see the following new errors in the Sitecore logs when republishing the 10.3.1 site:
36148 14:13:02 ERROR [Content Testing]: Error in Experience computed index field. 
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRuleCondition[T](Database database, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRuleConditions[T](Database database, XElement element, Rule`1 result)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRule[T](Database database, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.ParseRules[T](Database database, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference.ParseSettings(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.ExtractReferences(XmlNode deviceNode, Language language, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.GetRenderings(DeviceItem device, Boolean checkLogin)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.PersonalizationConfiguration.GetPersonalizationRenderings(Boolean includedInTheTest)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Extensions.ItemExtensions.GetExperience(Item item, IPersonalizationTestExperienceService personalizationTestExperienceService)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.Experience.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.TrackingSiteContextExtension.Tracking(SiteContext context)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Configuration.CurrentSiteContext.get_ExplicitConsentForTrackingIsRequired()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.TrackingServicesConfigurator.<>c.<Configure>b__0_5(IServiceProvider provider)
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at ... CUSTOM CODE FILE

36624 17:00:52 ERROR [Content Testing]: Error in Personalize component computed index field. 
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRuleCondition[T](Database database, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRuleConditions[T](Database database, XElement element, Rule`1 result)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.GetRule[T](Database database, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Rules.DefaultRuleFactory.ParseRules[T](Database database, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference.ParseSettings(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.ExtractReferences(XmlNode deviceNode, Language language, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.GetRenderings(DeviceItem device, Boolean checkLogin)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.PersonalizationConfiguration.GetPersonalizationRenderings(Boolean includedInTheTest)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Extensions.ItemExtensions.GetNumberOfPersonalizationComponent(Item item)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.PersonalizeComponent.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.TrackingSiteContextExtension.Tracking(SiteContext context)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Configuration.CurrentSiteContext.get_ExplicitConsentForTrackingIsRequired()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.TrackingServicesConfigurator.<>c.<Configure>b__0_5(IServiceProvider provider)
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at ... CUSTOM CODE FILE


The errors reference specific lines of custom code which follow this pattern:
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.Rules;
using Sitecore.Rules.Conditions;

public class MyCustomRule<T> : TrueCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
   private readonly IMyCustomCookieService _myCustomCookieService;

   // The code is failing on the call to GetService()
   public MyCustomRule() : this(ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyCustomCookieService>())
   {
   }
}

In the project by which IMyCustomCookieService is referenced, I do see that the service is registered using custom DI:
container.Register<IMyCustomCookieService, MyCustomCookieService>(ScopeType.Transient);

Otherwise, the ServiceLocator.GetService() is used wherever IMyCustomCookieService is needed.
So far, it is unclear which issues may be presenting (if any) as a result of these errors. How might I go about resolving the errors?
Additional Information
I have isolated the issue and can reproduce the error by republishing a specific page item that has a personalized rendering whose datasource is set based on the evaluation of a custom condition.
In plain English, the condition can be described as "where the user has MyCustomStatus in their cookie". That custom condition item is located at /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/ACME Status/My Custom Status (template is /sitecore/templates/System/Rules/Condition).
That item references the code that is failing via the Type field:
ACME.Feature.User.Rules.Conditions.MyCustomStatus,ACME.Feature.User

Looks like the SiteContext is not available. Where exactly are you making the call from? Does it originate from an API Controller?

And your custom rule requires MyCustomCookieService to evaluate condition? Which means that it requires information about tracking consent? That should never be a case in a computed field as they should be computed in background process, without any user context.

I have added more information under the "Additional Information" heading. The error is triggered when republishing a page that has a personalized rendering whose datasource is calculated based on the outcome of a custom condition. The custom condition code is the location of the failed call to GetService().

Can you post code for MyCustomCookieService. It looks like it has a tracking service dependency, which in turn calls gets ExplicitConsentForTrackingIsRequired during contructor. Thats failing due to SitecoreContext not being available. This is new in sitecore 10 which explains why only seeing it now: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-or-disable-web-tracking-based-on-visitor-consent.html
